# How to get the application theme of the manifest file android

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I have an android app that needs more than one theme. These themes are totally different from each other, but I need to know dynamically which theme is selected at the moment.

Here you can find an example of the application tag of my android app. Here you see the theme is set to Theme1, but it can be Theme2,Theme3,...

```
<application
    android:name="be.genius.gticket.adapter.MyApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="gticket"

    android:theme="@style/Theme1" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int themeId = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.theme;


switch (themeId)
        {
        default:
        case THEME_DEFAULT: // use the theme names in cases as per requirements
            break;
        case THEME_WHITE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_White);
            break;
        case THEME_BLUE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
            break;
        }
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: when i change THEME_DEFAULT to R.style.Theme1 then it will works. Thx good job!